PostgreSQL does not recognise NULL-value in the XML
I am trying to parse XML using PostgreSQL.
XML contains a null-value. The expected type of column is "int".
But Postgres treats the value as an empty (not null) string.
with data as ( 
select 
'<root>
    <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <row>
            <int_value xsi:nil="true"/>
        </row>    
    </test>
</root>'::xml val)
select int_value
from data x,
xmltable(
    '/root/test/row'
    passing val
    columns int_value int
)

I am expected to get query result with one field "int_value" of type "int" with null-value.
Actual result is error message:
ERROR: invalid syntax for type integer: "".


Since an empty string is not valid syntax for integer, do it like this.
...
select nullif(int_value, '')::integer as int_value
from data x,
xmltable(
    '/root/test/row'
    passing val
    columns int_value text
)


Yes, it works, thanks!

First search for "postgresql convert empty string to null", you will land on the function NULLIF e.g. here
This query transforms empty string to null and non-empty string cast to int
select nullif(int_value,'')::int int_value

Than change the column type of int_value (in XMLTABLE not in the result query)  to text and rewrite the select as follows:
with data as ( 
select 
'<root>
    <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <row>
            <int_value xsi:nil="true"/>
        </row>    
    </test>
</root>'::xml val)
select nullif(int_value,'')::int int_value -- here cast test to int
from data x,
xmltable(
    '/root/test/row'
    passing val
    columns int_value text  -- here text
)


Yes, it works, thanks!
